# Nifi - Installing specific App from list of web application

Tags: apache-nifi, cloudera, hortonworks-dataflow

NiFi is comprised of a number of web applications (web UI, web API, documentation, custom UIs, data viewers, etc)

Is it possible to install only specific app ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no easy way to do it, everythings is in the same JVM.

[image: Nifi architecture]

However nifi is open source, feel free to modify it for your requirement : https://github.com/apache/nifi

do you take a look at minifi project : https://nifi.apache.org/minifi/index.html ?